# Finding the mean and probabilities from an approximated probability density function

Tags: probability-distributions, numerical-methods

After a lot of calculations, I've ended up with an approximation of a continuous probability density function (pdf) please see this link:
[Approx PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiR1n.png)

This looks smooth but is in fact just many many point that build up the pdf.

I'm looking to find the mean of this distribution and then ultimately to be able to find percentiles of the distribution. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: If it's lots of individual points, you could just use the standard expectation formula to get the mean. If you don't mind having an approximation, perhaps consider Monte Carlo methods?

Comment: @BenCollister How would I do either of those methods? Since its a PDF I cant just sum product the x against y, it comes out massive.

Comment: To get the mean, you can compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) \, dx$ using a numerical method such as the midpoint method.

Comment: @littleO Thanks, yeh this seems obvious now you mention it. Worked perfectly using the trapezium rule!

Comment: you can use some Julia libraries for this, by example `StatsBase` that have a function [`ecdf`](https://juliastats.github.io/StatsBase.jl/stable/empirical/#StatsBase.ecdf) to evaluate the empirical distribution, from where you can get probabilities, percentiles, and so on. Also you can use other libraries for similar tasks, by example `KernelDensity`